# CSS: Appearance/Customise display different to actual display

Tags: css

I use the [Shared Counts plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shared-counts/) for displaying social media buttons on my blog.

I'm using a shortcode to display some buttons in a footer text widget on my homepage.  When I format the way they look in Appearance/Customise/Simple CSS I can get what I'm looking for.  However, for some reason, when I look at the page outside of the customiser the display is not the same (the buttons are all squashed together with no spacing).

Specifically, I'm looking to space the buttons evenly using:

```
      .shared-counts-wrap  {
       display: flex;
       justify-content: space-between;
      }
```

If it helps to visualise the problem, the page is here: https://richiesroom.com/

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue after reading [this post](https://sharedcountsplugin.com/2019/03/27/display-share-buttons-using-a-shortcode/) from the plugin author.  Once I customised the shortcode attribute where I was using it in the text footer widget everything worked as intended. :-)